# magento 2.4 : customer session get destroyed after payment

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.1

I am using magento 2.4.1, i have used plugin for payment gateway like - ccavenues , payu but issues it that after payment it gets redirected to **"checkout/cart/"**

While debugging it seems session is getting destoryed please help me with issue as i am bit new and could not trace issue.

Answer (score 0):

put log in the file

**vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator.php**

it seems like issue with the set value of last quote id and order id

Answer (score 0):

Finally , I found the solution

open the file

> `vendor\magento\module-checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator.php`

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$orderDatamodel = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
 $orderId   =   $orderDatamodel->getId();
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
if ($orderId && is_numeric($orderId)) {
           // $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
            if ($order && $order->getId()) {
                $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($order->getQuoteId());
                $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($order->getQuoteId());
                $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
                $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
                $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());
            }
        }
```

Hope ,this will help to others.

Comment: Whereabouts in that file do you add that code? Is it in the construct function?